A Counterexample in Fubini's Theorem by Kolmogorov
Let $E = [0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $f: E \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y) = 2^n, \ \text{if}\ x \in [\frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}] \ \text{and} \ y \in [\frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}); \ \ f(x,y) = -2^{2n +1}, \ \text{if} \ x \in [\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, \frac{1}{2^{n}}) \ \text{and} \ y \in [\frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}); f(x,y) = 0, \ \text{otherwise}.$
How to compute $\int_{0}^{1} \Big(\int_{0}^{1} f(x,y)dx \Big)dy$ and $\int_{0}^{1} \Big(\int_{0}^{1} f(x,y)dy \Big)dx$ and show that it gives us $0$ and $1/4$, respectively? I tried to explicit the sets $E_y = \{x \in [0,1]: (x,y) \in E\}$ and $E_x$ to compute these integrals, but i got completely confused with that and didn't get the result.
Can anyone help me with this?

It will be easier to see how integrate it if you write it down as $$f(x,y)=-2^{2n+1}\chi_{\left[\frac1{2^{n+1}},\frac1{2^n}\right)}(x)\cdot\chi_{\left[\frac1{2^n},\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)}(y)+2^n\chi_{\left[\frac1{2^n},\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right]}(x)\cdot\chi_{\left[\frac1{2^n},\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)}(y)$$
